# Control AudioSession from code

Tags: iphone, ios5, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

In my project i have a function that play music

```
-(void)playPlin {
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
// Set up audio session, to prevent iPhone from deep sleeping, while playing sounds
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                         sizeof (category),
                         &category
                         );

//UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
OSStatus result = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                                          sizeof(category), &category);

if (result){
    NSLog(@"ERROR SETTING AUDIO CATEGORY!\n");
}

result = AudioSessionSetActive(true);
if (result) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR SETTING AUDIO SESSION ACTIVE!\n");
}

NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chimes" ofType:@"wav"];
NSData *sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
NSError *audioError = nil;

AVAudioPlayer *alarmAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData error:&audioError];
[sampleData release];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];



if(audioError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"An audio error occurred: \"%@\"", audioError);
}
else {
    [alarmAudioPlayer play];
}       }
```

The file play ok but i have three issue:

1.how can I make that the audio file starts not from the beginning but from the number of second that i pass? for example, if i step value 300 audio file should start from the second 300 of it

2.How can i set volume of audio file?

3.How can i set loop property of it?

thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all pretty clearly laid out in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067).

1) Use the `playAtTime:` method call instead of `play`. Pass the time in seconds.

2) Set the `volume` property on the `AVAudioPlayer`. Note that this is the gain of the player, and will be modulated with the current system volume.

3) Set the `numberOfLoops` property. Assign a huge value like `NSIntegerMax` to keep looping indefinitely.